# Fastest way to get vertex attributes from igraph edges

Tags: python, igraph

I'm looking for a concise (and fast!) of retrieving vertex attributes from an `igraph.Graph` without iterating through each edge. For the most basic example, I want a list of all source nodes in the edge list. The best I can find is:

```py
g = ig.Graph.full(100)
sourcelist = [e.source for e in g.es]
```

Is there something faster? Speed really matters in this application. Bonus points if it can come as a np array. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the edgelist and extracting the first item of each tuple is going to be faster:

```
>>> timeit('[e.source for e in g.es]', 'from igraph import Graph; g = Graph.Full(100)', number=1000)
1.4157595419999893
>>> timeit('[e[0] for e in g.get_edgelist()]', 'from igraph import Graph; g = Graph.Full(100)', number=1000)
0.2647179579999914
```

Unfortunately there's still a bit of overhead due to the construction of a tuple for each edge in `g.get_edgelist()`, and you won't end up with a NumPy array unless you wrap the expression in `array()`. In theory it is possible to use `ctypes` to call into igraph's C core directly and get a raw `igraph_vector_int_t`, which you can then wrap into a NumPy array with zero copies and extra tuples being made, but it is going to be fragile because you need to know how the internal fields of an `igraph_vector_int_t` are laid out.

Comment: Thanks, @Tamás. I have been debating transferring my program from python to c anyway due to speed considerations not directly related to igraph. So, maybe this is just another reason to do so.